# error reading xml file in mac os java applet

Tags: java, xml, macos, file

Every once in a while, I get the following exception when trying to read in my XML file. The file looks ok and seems to be valid. Any hints would be appreciated.

I am trying to read the config file in mac os via applet and i get the above error.

java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.

Best regards,
SAGAR.

Comment: "Any hints would be appreciated."  1) Ask a question.  2) Post code.

Answer (score 0):

[This may help](http://www.danielschneller.com/2008/01/saxparseexception-1-1-premature-end-of.html).

You also need to run your XML through a validator. Having a schema would help because Java's XML APIs support the ability to associate a schema with a parser so the parser will automatically validate the document for you.